# How to get campaign data in Google Analytics (v4) for Android?

Tags: android, google-analytics, android-broadcast

I was trying to setup google Analytics for campaign measurement and was going through this link: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns#general-campaigns

The code in this link is something like this:

```
// Get tracker.
Tracker t = ((AnalyticsSampleApp) getActivity().getApplication()).getTracker(
    TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);

// Set screen name.
t.setScreenName(screenName);

// In this example, campaign information is set using
// a url string with Google Analytics campaign parameters.
// Note: This is for illustrative purposes. In most cases campaign
//       information would come from an incoming Intent.
String campaignData = "http://examplepetstore.com/index.html?" +
    "utm_source=email&utm_medium=email_marketing&utm_campaign=summer" +
    "&utm_content=email_variation_1";

// Campaign data sent with this hit.
t.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder()
    .setCampaignParamsFromUrl(campaignData)
    .build()
);
```

My question is how to get the campaignData from an incoming event?

Kindly help.

Comment: You should have different exports of Apks for each campaign and put campaign name in it

Comment: Could you please elaborate or support with a piece of code? @sajad

Answer (score 2):

There are two types of campaign tracking:

1. **Install Campaigns**,
2. **General Campaigns**.

**Install Campaigns** tracks app installs and is done by including specific intent to your app manifest.

**General Campaigns** are tracking launches of your apps (app is already installed and user is clicking on a deep link, e.g. like: *app://myapp/deeplink?**utm_source**=...*)

In your example (generic campaigns), campaign data are supposed to come from this specific deep link.

In this example ("*examplepetstore.com/index.html?utm_source=**email**&utm_medium=**email_marketing**&utm_campaign=**summer**&utm_content=**email_variation_1***") text in bold is your campaign data and your marketing team is creating it. GA library recognises these parameters in the `setCampaignParamsFromUrl()`.

**General Campaigns** or **Launch Campaigns** allows you to track which source (utm_source, utm_campaign, utm_medium) was used to open an already installed app. This is done via deep linking mechanism and if you are familiar with deep linking - you are good to go.

See [here](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking) for deep linking implementation for Android.

In your *AndroidManifest.xml*

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

This presumes you have MainActivity class in your app.